# extract time and compare if greater than another time

Tags: excel, excel-2016

[image]how to extract the time from the cell value below

[image]

then compare it if greater than 9:30 PM.

Is there also conditional formatting for this scenario?

Comment: Try `=A1-INT(A1)` to get the time part and then just use `=B1>C1`.

Comment: Is the date shown formatted as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
A1:  1/20/2017 Friday 08:22 PM
B1:  9:30 PM

=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),2))+1,10) )> B1
```

will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`

To return the difference between the two times:

```
=B1 - MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),2))+1,10)
```

and format the cell containing the formula as `h:mm`

**EDIT** Seeing that there is a colon after the time digits, I would alter the formulas to remove it:

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),2))+1,10),":"," ",2)) > B1
```

> OR

```
=B1-SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),2))+1,10),":"," ",2)
```

**EDIT**  Explanation

> SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),2)  *Replace 2nd space with CHAR(1)*
>
> FIND(CHAR(1), ...  *return the location of the CHAR(1)*
>
> MID(...  *extract the part of the string that starts with the CHAR(1)*
>
> *NOTE: we use CHAR(1) because that is a character that would probably never be entered into a text string*

Comment: Oh , i removed the colon in the time cell and it works! , can you explain your code? thanks!

Comment: @FrancisSaul We use the text functions to replace the 2nd space with a known character, then extract everything after that; which is the time string.  You shouldn't have to do anything with the colon, unless either your data is not as you show; or your local time separator is not the colon.  Or if the string is a "real time" formatted as you show it, in which case the formula would have returned an error.

Comment: please see above picture where i removed the ":" , i generate those values from C#. I'd like to ask what is the value of the 2nd space in my cell field? thanks!

Comment: @FrancisSaul **AH** I did not see the colon "after" the time digits.  I will edit my response.  I don't understand your question about the *value of the 2nd space*

Comment: =TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),2))+1,10) )> B1     can you explain what is MID, FIND , SUBSTITUE and CHAR(1),2)) + 1,10 does?

Comment: @FrancisSaul  You can use the Formula Evaluation tool to figure that out.  But I've added a more detailed explanation than what I gave in my previous comment, to my answer.